# Proving that a system of $m$ homogeneous linear equations in $n$ variables has a solution in which not all $x_i=0$ if $n>m$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I haven't taken linear algebra, so I don't really understand how matrices work. Sadly, all the proofs that I've found of the statement in the title require some understanding of matrices, so I've been trying to prove it without them. A friend gave me a hint on how to prove it without matrices but I became stock. I was able to complete half of the proof I and was wondering if someone could help me finish it.

---

Say we have the system of $m$ homogeneous equations in $n$ variables

$$E_i=a_{i,1}x_1+...+a_{i,n}x_n=0$$

$m<n$ and $1≤i≤m$. We may assume that all the equations are linearly independent, since otherwise, we could remove equations until getting a linearly independent set (because the solutions of such set would be the same). Without loss of generality say that $a_{1,1}≠0$ (some coefficient must be), multiply the first equation by $(a_{1,1})^{-1}$, so that the coefficient of $x_1$ is $1$. Now substract $(a_{i,1})(a_{1,1})E_1$ from $E_i$ for all $i≠1$, so that we get a system of linear equationd in which only the first equation contains the $x_1$ variable. We can now, again, without loss of generality, repeat the process with $E_2$ (we may assume that at least one of the coefficients $a_{2,j}$ is nonzero since otherwise $E_2$ and $E_1$ would be linearly dependent). So we repeat the process $m$ times until we get the following set of equations

$$E_1=x_1+0+...+0+Z_{1,m+1}x_{m+1}+...+Z_{1,n}x_n=0$$
$$E_2=0+x_2+...+0+Z_{2,m+1}x_{m+1}+...+Z_{2,n}x_n=0$$

$$...$$

$$E_m=0+0+...+x_m+Z_{m,m+1}x_{m+1}+...+Z_{m,n}x_n=0$$

The only thing I need in order to prove the theorem is for one of the coefficients left to be nonzero, that is, for some $Z_{i,j}x_{j}$ left to be nonzero. How could one prove this last part of the proof?

---

I would gladly appreciate any help/thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_{m+1} = \ldots = x_n = -1$,

then we have
$$E_1=x_1+0+...+0-Z_{1,m+1}-...-Z_{1,n}=0$$
$$E_2=0+x_2+...+0-Z_{2,m+1}-...-Z_{2,n}=0$$

$$...$$

$$E_m=0+0+...+x_m-Z_{m,m+1}-...-Z_{m,n}=0$$

Hence

$$x_1=Z_{1,m+1}+...+Z_{1,n}$$
$$x_2=Z_{2,m+1}+...+Z_{2,n}$$

$$...$$

$$x_m=Z_{m,m+1}+...+Z_{m,n}$$

Hence we have found a non-zero solution. In general, there is nothing special about setting $x_{m+1} = \ldots = x_n = -1$, we can set those to be arbitrary number (make one of them non-zero if you want the solution to be non-trivial) and then solve for $x_1, \ldots, x_m$.

Comment: But the issue is that such a step wouldn't work if all the $Z_{i,j}$ came out as $0$. So how could we prove that some of them are nonzero in order to then apply your step?

Comment: In that case, the solution is of the form of $x_1=\ldots=x_m =0$ and $x_{m+1}=\ldots = x_n  = -1$.

Comment: Imagine $m=n-1$. Let us do what you are saying of making $x_1=...=x_m=0$. Then, the first system of linear equations we had would read as simply $a_{i,n}x_n=0$, and $x_n$ would have to be zero, so the theorem would be wrong...wouldn't it?

Comment: We set $x_n$ first, hence making sure the solution is non-zero, then express $x_1, \ldots, x_m$ in terms of $x_n$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand. If $m+1=n$, after substituting and eliminating we get $$E_i=x_i+Z_{i,n}=0$$. If all the $Z_{i,n}$ are zero, then $x_1=...=x_m=0$. Substituting into our fist linear system of equations we get $$E_i=a_{i,1}(0)+...+a_{i,m}(0)+a_{i,n}x_n$$ so $x_n=0$.

Comment: Suppose by setting $x_n = 1$, you set reaches $E_i = x_i + Z_{i,n}=0$ and you realizeds that $Z_{i,n}=0$, then $x_1=\ldots = x_m =0$. As you substitute back to the initial system, we have $a_{i,n}x_n = 0$ because $a_{i,n}=0$.

Comment: For example, if you want to solve the problem, $x_1 + 0(x_2) = 0$. you can set $x_2=1$ and obtain $x_1 = 0$.

Comment: How would you know $a_{i,n}=0$? I'm sorry, this isn't obvious to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70353/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-leo).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps to think about the simplest possible case.  When does
$$
a_1x_1+a_2x_2 =0
$$
have a solution different from
$$
x_1=x_2=0?
$$